# IP address conflict

Tags: windows-7, ip

We have eight devices on our network. Only one, an HP Pavilion dv7 Notebook, has recently (last 2 weeks)developed an issue maintaining internet access due to "IP Address Conflict". It picks up an IP address that begins with 169.xxx.xx.xx. It is supposed to have an address 192.xxx.xx.xx. All other devices stay connected the internet.

Problem happens whether attaching via hardwire or wireless connection to the router. Router is connecting to our Brighthouse internet service provider and uses dynamic IP addressing. Power cycling the router resets the IP address to the correct range (192.) but within a few hours IP address becomes 169.xxx.xx.xx.

Is problem in my network card or originating from the ISP? I'm suspecting a local problem since only one device is having an issue.

Comment: Can you tag your question with your OS?

Comment: 192.168.x.x. is an RCC1918 IP. That one should not be routable to outside parties. Hence the problem most likely is on your local network.

Comment: Can you log into the router and see which devices are connected (leave the HP pav. off). Try to see if you can ping the device with the same MAC as the HP has. If there is one then either you played around with **unique** MAC settings and have multiple 'unique' values (which obviously causes problems when they are assumed to be unique) or someone cloned the MAC from your laptop for some weird reason, and is in range of your wireless and has your wireless key,

Comment: Also mention if you played with VMs or not.

Comment: I'd probably start simple with resetting the OS network stack...

Comment: The 169 IP address is not a valid address, rather its an address used by DHCP when it can't get a valid address.  Problem is most likely not with your hardware - its most likely an address pool which is too small (this is programmed in your router) and/or an issue with the DHCP client on the HP device.

Comment: @Hennes you mean RFC not RCC, worth reading comment after and while writing it, to avoid typos. Especially since they are not editable after 5min.

Comment: @davidgo I'm thinking it must be something in my laptop and not the router because problem occurs on only this device. Router (supposedly) is configured for 256 devices. How should I chase down the DHCP client on the HP device? I've checked for a driver update for this network card. I must add that this is a relatively new occurrence.

Comment: Router cant be configured for 256 addresses (network, broadcast, gateway).

Answer (score 0):

Since resetting the router allows the computer to receive an address, the computer's network card must be working, and since all other devices can connect to the Internet, it is not your ISP's problem.  Thus, it must be a problem on your router.

The problem is most likely on your DHCP server, which is in your router.  The computer sends out a DHCP request, but for some reason the request doesn't get answered by the router.  When Windows cannot obtain an IP address, it resorts to picking one in the 169.xxx.xxx.xxx range.

Comment: Assigned static IP to  laptop yesterday. Will see how this works out. Thanks for your comments.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried assigning a static IP to the laptop?

When your computer/laptop sends a DHCP request and does no receive any IPs from the router, it sets itself an IP from  the range 169.254.x.x (with subnet-mask 255.255.0.0). This is called APIPA.

The problem here seems to be most probably at your computer rather than the router. You might want to try this:
open Device Manager > right-click Network adapters > Scan for Hardware changes.

If not:
Since you say the issue is due to "IP Address Conflict", I suspect that, less likely, the DHCP IP network on the router may be configured to smaller subnet size. Make sure the DHCP on the router has 192.x.x.x **/24** (or subnet-mask **255.255.255.0**)

Comment: Assigned static IP to  laptop yesterday. Will see how this works out. Thanks for all the suggestions.